# Using Paperclip with files already on Amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am building a Rails application that works with videos.  I am using an encoding service that encodes my video and places the encoded file along with some thumbnails in a specified location on my s3.  I am able to access the video via AWS:S3 like so:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.find 'videos/36/base/video.mp4', 'my-bucket-name'

-- or --

AWS::S3::S3Object.value 'videos/36/base/video.mp4', 'my-bucket-name'
```

What I would like to do is manage these files with Paperclip once I get notified from my encoding service that the encoding is complete.  Not sure how to do this.  Here is what I have so far:

```
class Encoding << ActiveRecord::Base

   has_attached_file :video,
                :url => ':s3_domain_url',
                :path => 'videos/:video_id/:encoding_type/basename.:extension',
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => {:access_key_id => AppConfig.s3.access_key_id,
                                    :secret_access_key => AppConfig.s3.secret_access_key,
                                    :bucket => AppConfig.s3.bucket
                },
                :s3_permissions => 'authenticated-read',
                :s3_protocol => 'http'
end

class Video << ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_encoded
     encoding = encodings.build
     encoding.video = ## WHAT GOES HERE ??
     encoding.save
  end
end
```

Thanks!  Really appreciate your help

-- jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  Simplely set the the paperclip attributes directly.  So my after_encoded method looks like this

```
   def after_encoded
     encoding = encodings.build
     encoding.video_file_name = @video_details['url'].split('/').last
     encoding.video_content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(encoding.video_file_name).to_s
     encoding.video_file_size =  @video_details['size']
     encoding.video_updated_at = Time.now
     encoding.save
   end
```

Works great